# How to use the item price as the text frequency in a wordcloud?

Tags: python, word-cloud

I have the following dataframe and need to use a wordcloud for analysis in python:

```
    Category Price
    Dog      500
    Cow      1000
    Goat     650
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['Dog', 'Cow', 'Goat'], 'Price': [500, 1000, 650] })
```

How do I write the code so that "Cow" is the largest text, followed by "Goat" etc. I tried creating 2 arrays: Category and Price, then multiplying the two and using the result as the text. However, the resulting array comes as "DogDogDog..." and "Goatgoatgoat" which is not what I want. Kindly assist.

Comment: please share the code you have so we can suggest where it went wrong

Comment: where is your code? What module do you use to create word cloud? Did you read documentation for this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an extra space, so the words get separated.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['Dog', 'Cow', 'Goat'], 'Price': [3, 4, 5] })

text = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    text += (row['Category'] + ' ') * row['Price']
print(text)
```

Output:

```
Dog Dog Dog Cow Cow Cow Cow Goat Goat Goat Goat Goat
```

Here is a more extended example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Lemon', 'Pineapple', 'Nut', 'Banana', 'Grape', 'Orange', 'Plum' ],
                   'Price':    [500,     1000,   650,     800,         3000,  900,      1100,    900,      1400   ]})

text = ''
for row in df.itertuples():
    text += (row.Category + ' ') * row.Price

wordcloud = WordCloud(
    width=800,height=800,
    min_font_size = 10,
    background_color='gold',
    collocations=False
).generate(text)

# plot the WordCloud image
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor=None)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0)

plt.show()
```

[image: example wordcloud]

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, my question has been answered